# Make an #include <header.h> only visible for its own library

Tags: c++, include

Is it possible to hide an

```
#include <header.h>  //from library B
```

from projects using the library A?

I need to keep the include there because otherwise my library A won't compile, but as that header is from other library B that shouldn't be visible for the main project, the main program tries to find that header.h and compilation fails.

Comment: Doesn't library B use any of the symbols defined in header.h?

Comment: Why won't A compile without it? Forward declaring class names may be all you need.

Comment: When your library wont compile without it, but using the headers of your library works without it, why arent you only including it in your .cxx files? remove it from your header, put it there.

Comment: Don't #include any headers in header files.  There's no reason to and it just causes this kind of confusion.  I have two headers: one the "local" includes and one the "global" includes.  The global one is for external consumption, the local one for internal (usually pre-compiled).  Apart from some minor differences, they are both the same.  The library #includes the first in its .cpp files, other libraries or programmers #include the second in theirs.

Comment: I like Robinson's suggestion, I will have a look, thanks

Comment: I am not so sure. You cannot just "not include any headers in header files". Sometimes you need the header, period. Also, putting everything into single "everything" headers means code that doesn't need headers at all will end up including them. And you lose track of what needs what. Include what you strictly need, and try to keep what you need to a minimum.

Comment: Why? When do you need the header?   A pre-compiled header will include what the library needs.  Trying to manage things at an individual compilation unit level is not something C++ gives you the tools to do easily.  Unless you enjoy trawling through compilation output to see where your circular dependency is.  I tried it your way for 10 years, then ditched the entire concept and did the above, never looking back :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it inside an `#ifdef` and define the symbol only when compiling library A:

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_FROM_LIBRARY_B
#include <header.h>  //from library B
#endif //INCLUDE_FROM_LIBRARY_B
```

**Update**: but probably the best option is @Robinson's suggestion above: don't include it in any header file, only in .cpp files when needed.

Comment: mmm, it didn't work. I can compile library A, no problem. But as I am developing now the project and the libraries I need to be able to compile everithing. thnx

Comment: @Jav_Rock, could you be a tad more specific about what exactly "didn't work" mean?

Comment: The only thing you have to pay attention to with my method is the order of #including things.  You will occasionally need to forward reference a class as well.  Otherwise, it's all good.